# How to Send a String to a Listbox of another application? Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, winapi, listbox

I want to know how to send a string to a List box of another Application. I already know how to do it but now I have encountered another problem. The string is sent to a different listbox or textbox. The code that I used is shown below. My question is is there a `hWndChildAfter` for `GetWindow()` like `FindWindowEx(hWndParent, hWndChildAfter, lpszClass, lpszWindow)`?

```
'Declarations/ETC
Const WM_SETTEXT As Long = &HC

Private Declare Auto Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
Private Declare Auto Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWndParent As IntPtr, ByVal hWndChildAfter As IntPtr, ByVal lpszClass As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As IntPtr
Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal uCmd As Integer) As IntPtr
Declare Function SendMessageHM Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Int32, ByVal wParam As Int32, ByVal lParam As String) As Int32

Enum GetWindow_Cmd
    GW_HWNDFIRST = 0
    GW_HWNDLAST = 1
    GW_HWNDNEXT = 2
    GW_HWNDPREV = 3
    GW_OWNER = 4
    GW_CHILD = 5
    GW_ENABLEDPOPUP = 6
End Enum

'Usage
Dim hWnd1 As IntPtr = FindWindow(FormClass, FormCaption)
Dim hWndR2 As IntPtr = GetWindow(hWnd1, GetWindow_Cmd.GW_CHILD)
SendMessageHM(hWndR2, WM_SETTEXT, 0, TextBox1.Text)
```

And I would like to do it like the code below but won't work.

```
'Declarations/ETC
Const WM_SETTEXT As Long = &HC

Private Declare Auto Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
Private Declare Auto Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWndParent As IntPtr, ByVal hWndChildAfter As IntPtr, ByVal lpszClass As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As IntPtr
Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal uCmd As Integer) As IntPtr
Declare Function SendMessageHM Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Int32, ByVal wParam As Int32, ByVal lParam As String) As Int32

Enum GetWindow_Cmd
    GW_HWNDFIRST = 0
    GW_HWNDLAST = 1
    GW_HWNDNEXT = 2
    GW_HWNDPREV = 3
    GW_OWNER = 4
    GW_CHILD = 5
    GW_ENABLEDPOPUP = 6
End Enum

'Usage
Dim MainWindowHandle As IntPtr
Dim ChildAfter As IntPtr
Dim ListBoxHandle As IntPtr
'Get the FormHandle
MainWindowHandle = FindWindow(FormClass, FormCaption)
'Get the ChildAfter of the ListBox
ChildAfter = FindWindowEx(MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, ChildClass, ChildCaption)
'Get the handle of the ListBox
ListBoxHandle = FindWindowEx(MainWindowHandle, ChildAfter, TargetClass, TargetCaption)
'Send String to ListBox
SendMessageHM(ListBoxHandle, WM_SETTEXT, 0, TextBox1.Text)
```

Any suggestions is very much appreciated.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How can I do that? I will use `GetWindow()` first before using `EnumChildWindows`?

Comment: Start by reading the docs

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Can you make an example on how to do this? I can't figure out how to.

Comment: There are a gazillion examples available.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've tried my best but didn't come up with the right code. All the examples that I had seen aren't helping me. Is it possible if you can teach me how to do it specifically? I've run out of hope on doing this.

Comment: You should write a C++ program first.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan For what?

Comment: To learn how to do this. Otherwise you'll not know whether the problem is your basic approach, or your p/invoke.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'll try to but I'm not very familiar to C++. Thank you for your help.